# Access a button attached to Custom Cells header file

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have a uitableviewcontroller (mainTVC) which contains several custom uitableviewcells.

The uitableviewcontroller is the front screen of a swrevealview (https://github.com/John-Lluch/SWRevealViewController) - I need to attach the revealtoggle function to a button within one of the custom cells to reveal a messages screen in the rear view.

The button is attached as a IB Outlet in the custom cells header file as follows -

**msgPost.h:**

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *msgsBtn;
```

The custom cells msgPost.h file is then included in the mainTVC.m file - I'd like to write a function that is triggered when the button is clicked - basically it needs to do the following -

```
- (void)buttonImpMsg
   {
        NSLog(@"Back Button Pressed!");
        [self.revealViewController revealToggle:nil];
        [self hide];
    }
```

but I'm not sure how to create access the msgsBtn property from the mainTVC.m file - any tips?

**EDIT**

Basically the thing I need to know is how to access the buttons click action from the parent uitableview controller - (the button is attached as an ibOutlet to the custom cells .h file which is imported into the uitableviewcontrollers m file)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be done via selectors.

Define selector properties in your custom cell class definition (CustomCell.h file):

```
@property SEL buttonPressedSelector
@property id buttonPressedTarget
```

Put this in your custom class, to method, which is called when your button is pressed:

```
-(IBAction)buttonPressed:(id)sender
{
    [self.buttonPressedTarget performSelector:self.buttonPressedSelector];
}
```

Put this into your view controller:

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    CustomCell *cell = (CustomCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"myCell"];
    // Your code...
    cell.buttonPressedSelector = @selector(cellBtnPressed);
    cell.buttonPressedTarget = self;
}

-(void) cellBtnPressed
{
    NSLog(@"Button Pressed Event in your View Controller.");
    // Your code is here
}
```

In my example CustomCell is your msgPost, View Controller is mainTVC.

Answer (score 0):

You need to link the button to the method by i.e. ctrl-clicking the button in Interface Builder and dragging from the button to the "File's owner" icon.

Comment: cheers - but i have done this - it is attached to the custom cells (msgPost.h) header file as an IB outlet - my question is how can I access this property from the parent uitableviewcontroller . m file.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand the flow of what you want to achieve

Comment: no worries - to explain - the customCell contains a button - the button is attached to the custom cells header file as an ibOutlet (called msgsBtn) - the customcells header file is then imported into the parent uitableviewcontrollers m file - I want to access the click action on the msgsBtn from the parent uitableviewcontrollers m file - but dont know how to do this

Comment: You have a button in the custom cell (msgPost). When this is tapped, what action do you want to run? A method in the tableviewcontroller?